# Restangular POST body empty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest, restangular

I'm trying to make a request to `/api/sessions` with Restangular. My setup looks this way:

```
var data = { "email": "user@email.com", password: "userpass" }
Restangular.all('/api/sessions').post(data, params, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

However this sends the POST request, but without the JSON body.

Comment: I tried with `$http`. Works without any problems.

        `$http.post(data)`

Comment: Just resolved this. I was using an interceptor. Didn't return the element from the interceptor. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

> **post**(subElement, elementToPost, [queryParams, headers]): Does a POST  and creates a subElement. Subelement is mandatory and is the nested resource. Element to post is the object to post to the server

So shouldn't your request be:

```
Restangular.all('/api/sessions').post(data, {}, params, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

Comment: Just tried this. Still doesn't receive the JSON body. The request comes in, but the Rails server doesn't receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`var myData = { "email": "user@email.com", "password": "userpass" }
Restangular.all('/api/sessions').post(myData, {}, params, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`

It should work.

Refer Documentation: [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

Comment: But OP _wants_ to have query params as well, which you haven't shown

Comment: yupp... i give a thought for second.. now it's updated

Comment: Just tried this. Still doesn't receive the JSON body. The request comes in, but the Rails server doesn't receive the data.